# How require_once in joomla2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, require-once

I Have a problem about require_once in joomla.

In this file php:

```
components\com_test\views\__test_r5\tmpl\default.php
```

I want to include some file using this code:

```
require_once (JPATH_ROOT.DS.'/includes/General.php');
```

but require_once does not works

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Please explain in more detail what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path you are trying to include will evaluate to something like: `joomla//includes/General.php`. Notice the double slashes before *"includes"*.
The constant `DS` is defined to be a directory separator.

Try:
`require_once (JPATH_ROOT.'/includes/General.php');`
 (without `DS`)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
require_once(JPATH_SITE.DS."includes/General.php");
```

The JPATH_SITE will return your physical path upto : installation folder.

```
also JURI::root() will return your site url
```

Comment: DS is no longer needed, it has been deprecated and using it is discouraged.

Comment: @ValentinDespa Ok but JPATH_SITE will return the the physical path without last slashes(directory separator) thats why i prefer DS for this case

Comment: But you can ust use / (slash).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use @Fnatte variant.

Also have a look at the [**Joomla! constants**](http://docs.joomla.org/Constants) definitions and adapt where needed.