# How to include 3rd party library in Joomla in the proper way?

Tags: php, joomla

For particular reasons I want to use a thirdparty php graph&chart library (phpCHART) for a custom component that I'm developing for my Joomla 3.3 application.

For my first attempt including the library seems to fail causing the following error when I call the custom component via a main menu item:
[image]

What I did:

(step 1) I included the phpCHART library folder in /libraries of the joomla root directory (e.g. /libraries/phpChart_Lite/

(step 2) In the default.php file of the view of my custom component in included the line:

```
 require_once(JPATH_ROOT.'/libraries/phpChart_Lite/conf.php'); //pChart graph
```

(for this line I looked at the solution in [How require_once in joomla2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219043/how-require-once-in-joomla2-5))

I think the error is in step 2, but i'm not sure how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message appears to say the fault is in the phpChart file (specifically server/clsconf.php) rather than your component.  Did you update the SCRIPTPATH before uploading?

Comment: I did indeed by adding the line in conf.php : define('SCRIPTPATH',JPATH_ROOT.'/libraries/phpChart_Lite/');

Comment: Is conf.php a joomla file? If not, I don't think that JPATH_ROOT will be recognised.  That command is part of the Joomla framework only, and not a PHP command.  Try replacing "JPATH_ROOT" with the actual full path.